# What does "unlimited travel" means for the trampoline ticket (on Belgium rail)?

Tags: trains, public-transport, lille

I found recently through TSE the existence of the trampoline ticket. A ticket that allows you to get to Lille, from some selected stations in  Belgium, with unlimited travel.

I only found information about it in the Belgium rail website (http://www.belgianrail.be/fr/titres-de-transport/transfrontalier/lille/trampoline-1-jour.aspx). Is this a train only ticket? is it a regional ticket? What does unlimited travel mean? Does it mean only on train or does it include other transportations?

Answer (score 3):

According to [the SNCF website](http://www.ter.sncf.com/nord-pas-de-calais/offres/produits/trampoline), those tickets are only valid between Lille and Tournai or Lille and Kortrijk. It does not elaborate but "illimité" suggests you could go back and forth several times between those cities in the course of one day, which does not necessarily sound very attractive.

Comment: https://belgianrail.be/en/Mobility/Web/tickets-railcards/abroad/lille/trampoline-1-day.aspx now says between Lille and Tournai, Froyennes, Kortrijk, Mouscron & Herseaux